# the trait bound `actix_identity::Identity: FromRequest` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/krowemoh/a-web-app-in-rust-07-logging-a-user-in-1e0a) to create a simple website using actix-web, tera, and diesel.
I currently add sessions for logged user by utilizing actix-identity. As far as I understand, I need to attached a middleware to the App. But some errors popped up.

One of them says `the trait bound 'actix_identity::Identity: FromRequest' is not satisfied`.
I have tried to read the actix-identity docs, but no clue what is wrong with my code. Some says I maybe forgot a `return`, but couldn't find any.

I hope someone could give me a clue, as I only learned rust for few days now.

Here is the code

main.rs

```
use actix_web::{web, web::Data, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use tera::{Tera, Context};
use actix_identity::{CookieIdentityPolicy, Identity, IdentityService};

async fn login(tera: Data<Tera>, id: Identity) -> impl Responder {
    let mut data = Context::new();
    data.insert("head_title", "Login");

    if let Some(id) = id.identity() {
        return HttpResponse::Ok().body("Already logged in")
    }
    let rendered = tera.render("login.html", &data).unwrap();
    return HttpResponse::Ok().body(rendered)
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        let tera = Tera::new("templates/**/*").expect("Failed to parse template file");
        App::new()
            .wrap(IdentityService::new(
                CookieIdentityPolicy::new(&[0;32])
                    .name("auth-cookie")
                    .secure(false)
            ))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(tera))
            .route("/login", web::get().to(login))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
--- snip ---
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
tera = "1.15"
dotenv = "0.15"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] } 
diesel = { version = "1.4", features = ["postgres", "chrono"] }
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
actix-identity = "0.3"
```

Here are the full error message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `IdentityService<CookieIdentityPolicy>: Transform<actix_web::app_service::AppRouting, ServiceRequest>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:26:19
    |
26  |               .wrap(IdentityService::new(
    |  ______________----_^
    | |              |
    | |              required by a bound introduced by this call
27  | |                 CookieIdentityPolicy::new(&[0;32])
28  | |                     .name("auth-cookie")
29  | |                     .secure(false)
30  | |             ))
    | |_____________^ the trait `Transform<actix_web::app_service::AppRouting, ServiceRequest>` is not implemented for `IdentityService<CookieIdentityPolicy>`
    |
note: required by a bound in `App::<T>::wrap`
   --> /home/ikraduya/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/actix-web-4.0.1/src/app.rs:358:12
    |
358 |           M: Transform<
    |  ____________^
359 | |                 T::Service,
360 | |                 ServiceRequest,
361 | |                 Response = ServiceResponse<B>,
362 | |                 Error = Error,
363 | |                 InitError = (),
364 | |             > + 'static,
    | |_____________^ required by this bound in `App::<T>::wrap`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `actix_identity::Identity: FromRequest` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:32:41
    |
32  |             .route("/login", web::get().to(login))
    |                                         ^^ the trait `FromRequest` is not implemented for `actix_identity::Identity`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromRequest` for `(Data<Tera>, actix_identity::Identity)`
note: required by a bound in `Route::to`
   --> /home/ikraduya/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/actix-web-4.0.1/src/route.rs:185:15
    |
185 |         Args: FromRequest + 'static,
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Route::to`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/Srinivasa314/actix-web-example.git) to compare with my code, it works, but I could not find any significant difference.

Comment: Try upgrading to actix-identity 0.4.0.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but IT WORKS :) Thank you
But I guess, we need to use the same actix-web and actix-identity version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is unhelpful (there is an [open issue for this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22750)).

You're using actix-identity 0.3 which depends on actix-web 3 while your main app function is using actix-web 4 which causes Rust to include *both* actix-web 3 and 4 into your app. `actix_identity::Identity` implements `FromRequest` from actix-web 3, not actix-web 4, which is what the error message is trying to say.

To fix, you need to make sure the versions of the two crates are compatible. In this case, you can simply upgrade actix-identity to 0.4.0 which depends on actix-web 4.

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
actix-identity = "0.4"
```

Comment: I see, I understand it fully now. Thanks